# Swift error: Could not find an overload for '<' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
if (password.utf16 > 5) {

        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid", message: "Password must be greater then 5", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()

    }
```

i used the code as above and i got the error message : Could not find an overload for '<' that accepts the supplied arguments.

may i know how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
if count(password) < 5 {
...
}
```

Comment: Note: you can do `if count(password) < 5`, no need for the parenthesis around the condition.

Comment: Yep you're right, mind is still used to Objective-C :). Thanks for your comment, just edited my answer.